# TimePicker Dialog when pressing EditText

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, timepicker

This question has been asked before, but the answers from back then, doesn't seem to work in Android Studio anymore, or else i'm missing something.

I want a timePicker dialog to show up when you press the edit text area, to set the time in the editText. However, for some reason, the normal keyboard simply pops up when pressed. I'm not getting any errors, though it still doesn't seem to work.

here is the code:

```
final EditText Edit_Time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time_view_edit);

    Edit_Time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(TimeActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    Edit_Time.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                }
            }, hour, minute, true);
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();

        }
    });
```

the xml part of editText:

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/time_view_edit"
            android:text="20:00"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

If anyone can help, then it's much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: add this to your Edittext tag in xml `android:editable="false"` and `android:focusable="false"`

Comment: What about creating a normal TextView which looks like an EditText but isn't an actual EditText?

Comment: As said above already why not simply create a TextView for setting date or time instead of editext

Comment: @SripadRaj Thanks for the answer! That made it work!

Comment: @SimonA.CallaghanJensen Glad that could help. I will write the comment as answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add these properties to your `EditText` tag in xml to disable keyboard popping up

```
android:editable="false"
```

and

```
android:focusable="false"
```

**UPDATE:**

`android:editable="false"` is deprecated now.
use `android:inputType="none"` instead or in the code:

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: thank you very much. this code helped me a lot. the only change that i made was android:editable="false" for android:inputType="time" because the android studio told me that function was deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on androidx projects. Create `showTimePicker` method.

```
    private void showTimePicker(){
        Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(EditPharmacyActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

            }
        }, hour, minute, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }
```

And in `onCreate` method add followings to init the views.

```
        etOpenHours.setClickable(true);
        etOpenHours.setLongClickable(false);
        etOpenHours.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

        etOpenHours.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               
                showTimePicker();
            }
        });
```